# Kirby CMS - help understanding chaining and objects

Tags: php, kirby

We're working with the php-based CMS Kirby but are having trouble understanding where we can (and can't) use chaining (we're pretty green when it comes to php).

We have a product section like this:

```
|_Shop
  |_Sheets
    |_Sheet one
    |_Sheet two
  |_Bed spreads
    |_Bed spread one
    |_Bed spread two
```

And are trying to deliver a list of all the product child pages under each category.

How do we do this?

We keep seeing a lot of "Call to a member function on a non-object" errors which we're assuming has to do with the way we're chaining things - e.g. we've tried many ways of doing this but are currently trying:

```
$productPages = $pages->findByDirname('sheets, duvet-covers, bed-spreads, pillowcases, table-linen');
```

But are unsure how to find the children of these pages as adding `->visible()->children()` either to the end of `$pages` above or into the foreach loop like this results in errors:

```
<?php foreach($productPages->visible()->children() as $pageList) : ?>
```

Also, we can see that the $page variable has the `->visible()->children()` variables so assume we need to hand our `$productPages` variable over to the `$page` variable so we can use `visible()->children()` but are unsure how to construct things sorry.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get `Call to a member function on a non-object` errors when you use `$productPages->visible()->children()` is because `$productPages` doesn't contain any page results.

I *think* that is because you are using `findByDirname` - i don't believe this takes a list like that. And if it does, that function requires using the number too.

You will be better of using `$pages->find($uri, [$anotherUri])` which takes the uri path, rather than the dirname.

Or alternatively `$pages->findByUID('sheets', 'bed-spreads', 'pillowcases')` which is the dirname but without the number.

Check out the kirby cheatsheet - http://getkirby.com/content/02-docs/kirby-cheatsheet.pdf

Hope that moves you in the right direction.